# Как передать переменную в конструктор класса и использовать её для сохранения результата в Dart/Flutter?

Tags: строки, flutter, dart

Есть класс(виджет) во Flutter, необходимо несколько раз передать значения переменных, которые виджет использует для работы и имя переменной, в которой будет сохранён результат. Как это можно реализовать? Как я понимаю, передать в конструкторе что-то типа `String value="data"` и потом использовать
после приведения `var data=0` нельзя? Какие есть варианты?

Вот конструктор из обычного counter.

```
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.counter, this.increment})
      : super(key: key);
```

Можно сюда передать `this.value = String "data"`,а затем уже `data` использовать, как имя переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сразу скажу, написать этот ответ оказалось сложнее, чем я думал.
> Возможно вы тоже столкнетесь с какой-то проблемой при выполнении шагов ниже, поэтому пишите в
> комментарии, если что-то не так пойдет, и я дополню ответ, как буду свободен.

Да, это возможно с помощью рефлексии. Для **Dart** рефлексии на данный момент есть только один [официальный пакет](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html).

Но этот пакет не получится импортировать во **Flutter** проектах, во **Flutter** этот пакет не поддерживается.

На данный момент есть одна [альтернатива для **Flutter**](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable/install). Для получения переменной по имени вам нужно будет установить эту библиотеку, добавив следующее в `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  /// Эти 2 библиотеки нужны для генерации кода.
  build_runner: any
  built_value_generator: any

dependencies:
  /// Это сама библиотека
  reflectable: any
```

Затем вы можете получить переменные класса таким образом:

1. Создайте класс (класс может называться как угодно, главное - чтобы он наследовался от `Reflectable`), который будет содержать конфигурацию о том, какие возможности рефлексии вам нужны (например, чтение переменных по имени, вызов методов по имени и т.п. Их очень много, поэтому все перечислять не буду здесь).

   В вашем кейсе вам нужна `invokingCapability`, так как вы будете вызывать getter переменной, чтобы получить ее значение (`getter` необязательно создавать, он есть по умолчанию у любой `public` переменной в **Dart**). Вот пример для вашего кейса:

```
class Reflector extends Reflectable {
  // В super() можно передавать какие угодно capability, все они предоставляются библиотекой.
  // Достаточно просто импортировать библиотеку reflectable.
  const Reflector() : super(invokingCapability);
}
```

2. Пометьте класс, который нужно будет читать с помощью рефлексии вашим классом `Reflector`:

```
@Reflector()
class MyClass {
  String variable;
  
  MyClass(this.variable);
}
```

3. Создать файл `build.yaml` в корне проекта (там же, где и `pubspec.yaml`). В него поместить:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      reflectable:
        generate_for:
          - lib/main.dart # для чего генерировать код
        options:
          formatted: true
```

4. Запустить генерацию кода с помощью команды `flutter packages pub run build_runner build lib`. `lib` - это название папки, может отличаться в вашем случае.
5. После этого можно использовать рефлексию. Сделал пример для вашего кейса ниже:

```
void main() {
  // Инициализация, reflectable. Этот метод сгенерирован, поэтому если будет подсвечен красным, то нужно смотреть на шаги выше.
  initializeReflectable();

  // Объект, переменные которого мы будем доставать.
  MyClass myClassObject = MyClass('lalala');

  // InstanceMirror - инструмент работы с объектом через рефлексию.
  InstanceMirror instanceMirror = Reflector().reflect(myClassObject);

  // Так мы достанем содержимое переменной с названием 'variable';
  String variable = instanceMirror.invokeGetter('variable');
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, для моего уровня с ходу это не осилить, но внимательно изучу и протестирую.

Comment: @SergoSemenuyk не за что! Но вообще в вашем случае думаю такое решение будет излишним. Вы можете просто создать какой-нибудь метод или getter, например get result, который будет смотреть на String value. И если value == 'data', то метод/getter будет возвращать переменную data, если value == 'title', то метод/getter будет возвращать переменную title. И так далее. Просто с помощью switch или нескольких if проверяйте содержание строки и возвращайте переменную вручную, будет намного проще, а проще значит лучше.

Comment: это просто великолепно в своей простоте!

Comment: @SergoSemenuyk если проблема решена, поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку рядом с ответом, спасибо)